# Java Call class that created an object

Tags: java

I wonder know how to select, manipulate the class that created an object.

Code :

```
public myclass(){

       public anotherclass a = new anotherclass();    

}
```

anotherclass :

```
      //how to use the class that created this class ?
```

Comment: can you clarify your question? you want to edit myClass() object within another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the parameter of the `myclass` to the `anotherclass`-object:

```
public anotherclass{

    private myclass object;

    Public anotherclass(myclass object){

        this.object = object;

    }
}
```

You call your object like:

```
public myclass(){

       public anotherclass a = new anotherclass(this);    

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't, basically. If your other class needs to know either the instance or the class that created it, you should pass that information in via the constructor. For example:

```
public class Parent {
    private final Child child;

    public Parent() {
        child = new Child(this);
    }
}

public class Child {
    private final Parent parent;

    public Child(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

(That's making the parent *instance* available to the child - if you're only interested in the *class*, you'd pass `Parent.class` and the `Child` constructor would use a `Class<?> parentClass` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

By means of [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

Have MyClass instance in AnotherClass and create a constructor for it

```
class AnotherClass {

   private MyClass myClass;

   public AnotherClass(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;   
   }

   public void domeSomethignWithMyClass() {
       //myClass.get();
   }
}
```

and while creating from MyClass method, pass the instance

```
public void someMyClassMethod() {
    AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(this);
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Constructor that gets `myclass` as parameter:

```
public class Myclass
{
    Anotherclass a;

    public Myclass()
    {
         a = new Anotherclass(this);
    }
}

class Anotherclass
{
    private Myclass m;

    public Anotherclass(Myclass m)
    {
       this.m = m;
    }
}
```